# Is there a way to show at what percentage a selected document is similar to others on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I need to build a search engine using Elasticsearch and the steps will be as following:

1. Search on the search engine with a search string.
2. The relevant results will display and I can click on these documents.
3. If I select a document, I will be redirected to another page where I will see all the details of the documents and will have an option "More Like This" (which will return documents similar to the selected document). I know that this is done using the MLT query.
4. Now my question is: Except for returning documents similar to the selected one, how can I also return at what percentage the documents are similar to the selected one?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do.

#### using `function_score` query

`more_like_this` query is essentially a full text search, and it returns documents ordered by their relevance score. It could be possible to convert the score directly to a percentage, but it is not advised ([here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/getting-the-max-theoretical-score-for-a-search-query/16927/2) 
and more specifically [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/lucene/ScoresAsPercentages)).

Instead one can define a custom score with help of a [`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query, which can be designed so it returns a meaningful percentage.

This, of course, comes with additional cost of complexity, and the definition of "similarity" becomes more of an art than of science.

#### using `dense_vector`

One may opt to use the (yet experimental) [`dense_vector`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/dense-vector.html) data type, which allows storing and comparing dense vectors (that is, arrays of numbers of fixed size). Here's an article that describes this approach very well: [Text similarity search with vector fields](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch).

In this case the definition of similarity is as precise as it can possibly be: a distance of two vectors in a multidimensional space, which can be computed via, for instance, [cosine similarity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

However, such dense vectors have to be somehow computed, and the quality of said vectors will equal the quality of the similarity itself.

As the bottom line I must say that to make this work with Elasticsearch a bunch of computation and logic should be added outside, either in form of pre-computed models, or custom curated scoring algorithms. Elasticsearch out of the box does not seem to be a good percentage-similarity kind of deal.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going the route of using semantic search via `dense_vector`, as [Nikolay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5095957/nikolay-vasiliev) mentioned, I would recommend [NBoost](https://github.com/koursaros-ai/nboost). NBoost has a good out-of-the-box systems for improving Elasticsearch results with SOTA models.